# how to get full filepath while uploading a file in chrome

Tags: java, servlets

I am using Chrome. In my app uploading file from local folder,but it is taking only file name not full path. Is there any way to get the full path like storing it in different path n fetching that path. Please help me..

Comment: "it is taking" Who is "it"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756186/how-to-get-full-path-for-upload-a-file-in-jsp  possible duplicate

Comment: Google Chrome,When im uploading in Chrome browser

Comment: is it working fine in other browsers

Comment: in IE working fine..Chrome and Firefox taking only filename..

Comment: Chrome hides the full path by printing c:\fakepath\..., security measure.

Comment: Local filepath is useless on the server. It would only be of use to hackers. That's why browsers don't send it as security measure.